# Value Converter and Asyncronous web call results

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ivalueconverter

I have a value converter and I want to convert a key into an object and return in.  I convert the object by calling a web service...

Great... but the problem is the web service is async.  How would you typically get this done?

Comment: Seems like there is design issue. Please, provide more precise description with xaml and cs code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to the object in your ViewModel, in the ViewModel make your async call and when the completed event is called, set the property you are binding to and make sure to call the onchange event.

this way the item will be retrieved and when it runs through your converter you will already have the value.

Answer (score 2):

It is a design issue. You should keep in mind that the value converter is just a 'tiny' converter whose responsibility is converting value from one format to another. But to get data via asyn calls is biz-logic, which should be located in VM (MVVM for example.)